# get questions and answer from Amazon using cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio, amazon-product-api

I want to get all q&a for product from amazon,
I use this to get all reviews to this products,
but I don't know what is the class name I need to fill instead of `.reviews` in order to get the Customer questions & answers.

```
function parseHtml(html) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  // Load the reviews
  const reviews = $('.review');
  reviews.each((i, review) => {
    // Find the text children
    const textReview = $(review).find('.review-text').text();
    console.log(textReview);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Q&A is not part of the initial HTML of the page so Cheerio won't be able to see it.  It is lazy loaded via Javascript after the page loads when the Javascript in the page runs.

If you want to scrape it (as opposed to a getting it through an official API if that exists), then you will have to use something more capable than cheerio.

For example, you could use puppeteer which uses the Chrome engine to actually run the web page.  Then you would have a fully populated web page that contains the questions and you could extract them.

Or, you could reverse engineer how the Javascript in the web page loads the data and try to make that API request directly.

Note, the are also several iframes in that page too so you will have to make sure you are DOM searching in the right iframe.

Comment: I change to "puppeteer", when I wrote in the console this line: "document.body.querySelector('#ask-btf-container').innerText" I get the result I want (all questions and answers for the product from amazon. but when I wrote this line in the code, I get null (this error: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null) . maybe you have any ideas why? thanks!

Comment: @Shachar - You would have to show the exact puppeteer code you were using.  Puppeteer requires some special ways to access the DOM such as placing code inside `await page.evaluate(...)` and you might have a timing issue with "waiting" until the Javascript has loaded the content.